# Is it possible to pass data into a TestEventListener in the c++ Google test framework?

Tags: c++, googletest

I am using my own printer class in the google test framework to get some custom printing, as shown below:

```
class bsgtDefaultPrinter : public ::testing::EmptyTestEventListener {
    // Called before a test starts.
    virtual void OnTestStart(const ::testing::TestInfo& test_info) {
      printf("*** Starting test %s.%s\n", test_info.test_case_name(), test_info.name());
    }

    // Called after a failed assertion or a SUCCEED() invocation.
    virtual void OnTestPartResult(const ::testing::TestPartResult& test_part_result) {
        std::string msg = test_part_result.summary();
        char c = '|';
        msg = StripNewlines(msg,&c); // replace newlowith bar so result is all on same line
        printf("   %s%s\n",test_part_result.failed() ? "*** " : "",msg.c_str());
    }

    // Called after a test ends.
    virtual void OnTestEnd(const ::testing::TestInfo& test_info) {
        if (test_info.result()->Failed())
            printf("*** FAIL: ");
        else
            printf("*** PASS: ");
        printf("test %s.%s\n\n", test_info.test_case_name(), test_info.name());
    }
};
```

In my main() I am installing this printer as follows:

```
::testing::TestEventListeners& listeners = ::testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()->listeners();
delete listeners.Release(listeners.default_result_printer());
listeners.Append(new bsgtDefaultPrinter);
RUN_ALL_TESTS();
```

Is it possible to pass user data into the virtual method OnTestEnd of the custom printer? I want to report some extra data that was gathered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that without changing Google Test sources.

You would need to subclass `TestInfo` in order to append your custom data to the object, but you have no control over the instantiation of the actual parameter passed by to `TestEventListener::OnTestEnd`. The only way to control this instantiation is to modify Google Test source code so the data you want to gather is available at the point of calling `OnTestEnd`.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid of that. I can't even cache data in the printer class becuase that would not be thread safe